# JacksonConverter missing getObjectMapper() method

Tags: java, jackson, restlet

I'm using **Restlet** version **2.1.7** here is my Application class

```
public final class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = (Router)super.createInboundRoot();
    .
    .
    .

    List<ConverterHelper> converters = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters();
    JacksonConverter jacksonConverter = (JacksonConverter)converters.get(2);
    SerializationConfig serializationConfig = jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig();
    serializationConfig.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);

    return router;
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to upgrade to **Restlet** version **2.3.4** and I get compilation error for the next line:

```
        SerializationConfig serializationConfig = jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig();
```

The compilation error is that **JacksonConverter** no longer has the method **getObjectMapper()**

How can I overcome this compilation error? I will be happy for Application and/or Response solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is to add `JacksonConverter` in the next manner:

```
        List<ConverterHelper> converters = Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters();
        converters.add(new JacksonConverter());
```

Also, in order to set `SerializationInclusion` as `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL` I used the **annotation** `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` for every response class I use in my resources.

I could not find a more generic solution (in the application level), but this seems to work fine.